# How to extract Persian texts with Selenium in Python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

How to extract Persian texts with Selenium in Python??
The name variable should be text, but it seems to be empty

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
website="https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-3628808/%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%BA%D9%86- 
%D8%B2%DB%8C%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%86-%D8%A8%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D9%88- 
%DA%A9%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C-3000- 
%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%84%DB%8C-%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%AA%D8%B1/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Qazal\anaconda3\Lib\site- 
packages\selenium\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(website)
name=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="mr- 
4"]//a[@href="https://www.digikala.com/seller/AEVNX/"]')
name=name.text
name=name.encode("utf-8")
print(name)
```

[image: screenshot of that element]

Comment: what error are you getting currently?

Comment: I don't get an error, but the name variable is empty

Comment: can you post the screenshot of that element, that you want to get because there are multiple elements with your xpath. And I don't understand which text you need here

Comment: Yes, I posted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xpath expression `//*[@class="mr-4"]/div/a/p` is producing the following output:

```
*emphasized text*from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
url='https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-3628808/%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%BA%D9%86-%20%20%D8%B2%DB%8C%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%86-%D8%A8%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D9%88-%20%20%DA%A9%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C-3000-%20%20%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%84%DB%8C-%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%AA%D8%B1/'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
for name in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="mr-4"]/div/a/p'):
    print(name.text)
```

**Output:**

```
سراج احسان
رزاقی
```